# Why does timer Stop give a deadlock error?

Tags: go

I am creating this function to test creating and stopping timer. I am getting deadlock error when running it:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"


func main() {
    livenessTimer := &time.Timer{}
    livenessInterval, _ := time.ParseDuration("1m")
    for {
        fmt.Print("Timer started")
        livenessTimer = time.NewTimer(livenessInterval)
        select {
        case <-livenessTimer.C:
            fmt.Print(time.Now())
            fmt.Println("timer triggered")
        }
        if !livenessTimer.Stop() {
            // drain timer from channel if any
            fmt.Println("drain timer")
            <-livenessTimer.C
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Timer started2009-11-10 23:01:00 +0000 UTC m=+60.000000001timer triggered
drain timer
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox748850751/prog.go:21 +0x2e0
```

The documentation for `Stop` suggest to check the return value and drain the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the crucial part in the docs:

> ...assuming the program has not received from t.C already

In your case, the timer already fired, `Stop` returns false, and you start waiting on a channel with no other goroutines running, hence deadlock.

Comment: In this particular case, I find the documentation confuses people: it confused me, and I've seen several other cases of the same, including the OP's question. Probably the documentation itself could be reworded a bit to be clearer. (It's not *wrong*, it is just that the way it is phrased results in misreadings.)

Comment: There is actually a ticket open in regard to the unclear documentation: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27169